# Swift / Cloudkit predicate format

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I am trying to write a predicate using coordinates stored in a CloudKit database.  I am struggling to find any accurate documentation on the way to format it.  Here is what I've come up with:

```
NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation: (%K,%@) < 1000", "locationcoordinates")
```

I am getting the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Expected CLLocation argument for distanceToLocation:fromLocation:'

Can anyone help me correct this predicate?  I'm not sure what argument I need to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your predicate you have 2 parameters. the %K and %@ but are only supplying 1 value.

It should be something like

```
    var location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    var radiusInKilometers:CGFloat = 1000;
    var predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(location, %@) < %f", location, radiusInKilometers)!
```

Comment: So in swift I put this together 
`let location:CLLocation!
NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation: (%K,%@) < 1000", "locationcoordinates", location)`

Now the location keeps coming back nil.

Comment: I updated the answer with a CLLocation with coordinates 0,0. You have to enter your own coordinates for that. (Depending on where you want to search)